# JSON Deserialization into VB.Net object

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

I've read other answers, but I still seem lost. I am trying to bring JSON into my objects. I call a JSON string through an API, and I want to convert it into the objects after the RequestManager. Am I missing methods or something? Also, the returnChampions2 function is wrong. I posted part of the JSON string after the methods, it's really long.

Public Class RequestManager

```
Public Function returnChampions2(ByVal strRegion As String) As LeagueChampionMaster
    Dim strRequest As String = "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + strRegion + "/v1.2/champion?api_key=" + _APIKey
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueChampionMaster)(returnJSONRequest(strRequest))
End Function

Public Class LeagueChampionMaster
    Private _Type As String
    Private _Version As String
    Private _Data As LeagueChampion()
End Class

Public Class LeagueChampion
    Private _ID As Integer
    Private _Key As String
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Title As String
End Class
```

The json:

> {"type":"champion","version":"6.24.1","data":{"Jax":{"id":24,"key":"Jax","name":"Jax","title":"Grandmaster
>   at Arms"},"Sona":{"id":37,"key":"Sona","name":"Sona","title":"Maven of
>   the
>   Strings"},"Tristana":{"id":18,"key":"Tristana","name":"Tristana","title":"the
>   Yordle
>   Gunner"},"Varus":{"id":110,"key":"Varus","name":"Varus","title":"the
>   Arrow of
>   Retribution"},"Fiora":{"id":114,"key":"Fiora","name":"Fiora","title":"the
>   Grand
>   Duelist"},"Singed":{"id":27,"key":"Singed","name":"Singed","title":"the
>   Mad Chemist"},"TahmKench":{"id":223,"key":"TahmKench","name":"Tahm
>   Kench","title":"the River
>   King"},"Leblanc":{"id":7,"key":"Leblanc","name":"LeBlanc","title":"the
>   Deceiver"},"Thresh":{"id":412,"key":"Thresh","name":"Thresh","title":"the
>   Chain
>   Warden"},"Karma":{"id":43,"key":"Karma","name":"Karma","title":"the
>   Enlightened
>   One"},"Jhin":{"id":202,"key":"Jhin","name":"Jhin","title":"the
>   Virtuoso"},"Rumble":{"id":68,"key":"Rumble","name":"Rumble","title":"the
>   Mechanized
>   Menace"},"Udyr":{"id":77,"key":"Udyr","name":"Udyr","title":"the
>   Spirit Walker"},"LeeSin":{"id":64,"key":"LeeSin","name":"Lee
>   Sin","title":"the Blind
>   Monk"},"Yorick":{"id":83,"key":"Yorick","name":"Yorick","title":"Shepherd
>   of
>   Souls"},"Kassadin":{"id":38,"key":"Kassadin","name":"Kassadin","title":"the
>   Void
>   Walker"},"Sivir":{"id":15,"key":"Sivir","name":"Sivir","title":"the
>   Battle
>   Mistress"},"MissFortune":{"id":21,"key":"MissFortune","name":"Miss
>   Fortune","title":"the Bounty
>   Hunter"},"Draven":{"id":119,"key":"Draven","name":"Draven","title":"the
>   Glorious
>   Executioner"},"Yasuo":{"id":157,"key":"Yasuo","name":"Yasuo","title":"the
>   Unforgiven"},"Kayle":{"id":10,"key":"Kayle","name":"Kayle","title":"The
>   Judicator"},"Shaco":{"id":35,"key":"Shaco","name":"Shaco","title":"the
>   Demon
>   Jester"},"Renekton":{"id":58,"key":"Renekton","name":"Renekton","title":"the
>   Butcher of the
>   Sands"},"Hecarim":{"id":120,"key":"Hecarim","name":"Hecarim","title":"the
>   Shadow of
>   War"},"Fizz":{"id":105,"key":"Fizz","name":"Fizz","title":"the Tidal
>   Trickster"}}}

Comment: First, change the properties to Public otherwise you wont be able to access the data.  Then the property names need to match the json: `_id` wont match `id` - get rid of the underscores.  Also, the data should be a dictionary so you dont have to define a class for Fizz that is identical to "ziggy"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several issues.  You should know that if you copy the json to the clipboard, **Edit** -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste Json as Classes** Visual Studio will create the classes for you to give you a decent starting point.  In *this* case, the tool is a little dense and will create umpteen identical classes for "Fizz", "Shaco" etc.  You have already normalized that.

However, with all the properties `Private` you wont be able to access the data.  Then, the property names are wrong.  The json key of `id` or `key` will not map/deserialize to `_id` or `_key` because they do not match.  Lastly, the data collection should be a `Dictionary`.  The key for each player/champion/item will be used as the `Dictionary` key:

```
Public Class LeagueContainer
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property data As Dictionary(Of String, DataItem)
End Class

Public Class DataItem
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property title As String
End Class
```

usage:

```
Dim jstr = ... from where ever ...
Dim myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueContainer)(jstr)

' print the keys
For Each kvp In myData.data
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key)
Next

' what is Yorick's title?
Console.WriteLine("Yorick is '{0}'", myData.data("Yorick").title)
```

(Partial) Output:

> Jax
>   Sona
>   Tristana
>   Varus
>   Fiora
>   ...
>   Yorick is 'Shepherd of Souls'

Comment: What tool are you referring to with `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as Classes` ?

Comment: Visual Studio - I *think* as of VS2010  @MrGadget  I'll edit to make that clearer, it doesnt say *what* will create them

Comment: I found it...there're [special steps](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/generate-class-from-json-xml-in-visual-studio/) for that (thanks, Google).

Comment: Not very special IMO -  copy to clipboard, click, click

Comment: One does need a class file created and open and focused. If not, or you're focused on Solution Explorer, that doesn't work (I actually get Paste as XML classes with a clipboard full of JSON that does nothing...<shrug>).

Comment: Thank you. What would be the best way if I had different classes though, like dataItem and dataItem2 that were slightly different classes? I previously had both classes inherit from the same class I call Leagueobject. Then, I used different managers for each container but I also had a managerObject class that they inherited from. It's probably simpler to divide the classes.

Comment: Slightly different how? If it's just an extra property in DataItem2 that only occurs in some records, you can just add it to DataItem and those missing that element will still deserialize fine.

Comment: You could add props so the class can service both jsons - as long as the names are unique and the datatype matches.  I dont usually care for that approach because it means some or many properties are always null.  Besides, it doesnt cost anything to have 2 classes that are somewhat a like. Please click the check mark if this answers the question so this gets moved off the Unanswered list and consider upvoting it if it helped

Comment: No, everything works great now. I used the ElementAt to be able to pull the data because I wanted to be able to return a list of all names and stuff. Now, I just have to figure out how to sort it alphabetically.

Comment: The keys collection will cough up all the names, and the values collection will yield the same for the DataItem guys